# Is there anything legitimate that could change my Screensaver security settings?

Tags: windows-7, security, screensaver

A few days ago my laptop started displaying the "Locked" screen if I was away from my computer for a while.  Looking into my screensaver settings, it was set to do this after 10 minutes even though there was no active screensaver:

[image]

This is new.  It wasn't configured like this, and the behavior never happened until a few days ago. I get concerned when my settings get changed without my knowledge.

I'm using Windows 7 Pro, SP1 on a Lenovo laptop.  Nobody has access to my laptop; I work alone in an office.

- I am not on a domain or under a group policy.
- I manage my own Windows Update settings, and select which updates get installed. The only updates installed near the time of the change were two definition updates: one for Office 2010 (KB3115129) and one for Windows Defender (KB915597).
- I have the latest Avast antivirus, kept updated.
- I use NoScript with Firefox; practice safe browsing, and don't open unrecognized emails.

Does anyone have any ideas on what could have made this change?

Comment: Since "NONE" is selected, and the Wait time is available it's actually in an invalid state (the Wait and checkbox should be greyed when None is selected). I'd start considering disk and/or registry corruption..

Comment: Was it ever set to display a screen saver?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I thought that was the case, too, but it looks like we're mistaken.  [This](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/15322-screen-saver-password-protection-enable-disable.html) basic tutorial describes that you can select "none" and still have the lock screen timeout...

Comment: @TheStarvingGeek No, never a screensaver.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Hmm. Easy to repro. Set a screen saver. Enable "On resume..." Change the screen saver to "(None)" ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill Well isn't' that weird. I guess I've never tried that configuration...

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Neither had I till I saw this question and your first comment  ;) I haven't used a screen saver for many years.

Comment: @DavidPostill Are you saying that the "minutes" field is grayed out when "None" is selected?  Because mine is still active, as shown in the picture.  I don't have another Win7 box to experiment with...

Comment: @bitsmack No. It is still selectable, just as in your example. That's why I commented to Techie007 "Easy to repro.". You are seeing the "normal" Windows 7 behaviour. I've no idea what changed it in your case though :/

Comment: Are you certain you didn't leave your laptop unattended (and unlocked) at some point?

Comment: @DavidPostill No, I can't be certain. I seldom lock the OS since the computer stays in my office, which I (usually) lock up when I step out... And nobody around here is playful enough to prank me, AFAIK :)